# Meaning of + on javascript autoexecutable function

Tags: javascript

I've seen  function with a + symbol at the beginning like this

```
+(
function () {
  console.log("Hello World");
}
)
();
```

What does + means?

Comment: it turns the proceeding expression into a Number. for the example shown, it's silly because `;` would work

Comment: The `+` doesn't serve any purpose here.